# Trying to identify a movie from an image

Tags: story-identification, movie

[image: Unknown Movie I'm trying to identify]

Hi, I'm trying to identify the following movie from a picture.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Where did you get this picture? Is there any other information you could [edit] in to help someone find this for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome :)
I don't have anymore information, all I have is this image and have no clue what film it was from. I thought the things in the wall were body lockers but not sure.

Comment: Hopefully someone will come along and find it, or offer some helpful clues. In the mean time, why don't you take the [tour] and our [help]

Comment: @frostyPintsRob - Where did you come across this image?

Comment: It was on a friends computer desktop, but only saved as movie image :(

Comment: With the colorful bars at the top and bottom, this looks like it was a cropped screenshot from a website. There's some very flat shading on the metal to the right, which makes me think this is either older CG, or amateur work.

Comment: Hmmm... with a closer look, that's glass, not overly shiny metal, so maybe not as amateur. There are cable bundles visible within the background ports, so not body lockers most likely.

Comment: Well, what did your friend say where it's from?

Comment: Could this be from a video game?

Answer (score 13):

It's from the original *[Judge Dredd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge_Dredd_(film))* (1996) movie.

The image below shows Judge Rico in the same room, but from a different angle.

[image]

Comment: Specifically that's ex-judge Rico in the Janus lab, where he planned to make an army of clones of himself.

Comment: It is Judge Dredd, the scene in question is at around 1h 15m 40s

Comment: I guess 1996 is a bit early for Google - the only relevant picture I found with Google Image Search is of an out of stock trading card on Amazon (https://www.amazon.es/Trading-Tarjeta-centros-cuchillas-patines/dp/B017WC61VK) , which shows the same room in a different perspektive.

Comment: This pic shows Judge Rico, with the same background  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZbvZ.png

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in an image to improve the answer.